# Issue with getting POSTs to consistently pass through NSUrlCache when using UIWebView

Tags: ios, url, post, nsurlcache

By following the procedure illustrated here (http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/08/18/url-filtering-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone/) I am able to do URL filtering using UIWebView and a NSURLCache derived object.

The problem I am having is that for certain pages the cachedResponseForRequest() function is never being called for POST requests.

Does anyone have any experience getting this method to work to catch all POST requests, or any reasons why POSTs might only be caught sometimes?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - we were running into the same problem.  Did you try making a unique hash to append to the end of the URL, so that NSURLCache would have a unique url to associate with the returned data?  The problem with posts when using an api is that you're going to have a lot of requests sent to the same URL.  But if you make the URL unique with a meaningless hash, maybe cachedResponseForRequest will be able to locate your cached content.  If you try this and it works, please report back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution in form of `NSURLProtocol` stack. [WebViewProxy](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewProxy) provides a sample reusable implementation.